# Finishing Loop for Dice?

Tags: c#, if-statement, dice

I have a dice rolling game where you roll dice to score points. Currently, once 25 points is reached a message appears saying this player is the winner, but the program gets stuck in a loop that goes up to 50. Once a score limit is reached, I want to end the game but I am not really sure how to do that. I think I need a do-while loop, but I am not sure how to add in because the total points limit is in another class.

```
class Game
{ 
    private static void Main(string[] args)   ----- Main method:
    {
        if (gamemode == 1)
        {
               quickgame();
        } 

 }

    private static void quickgame()    ---- Game carried out
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nInstructions: Players take turns rolling all five dice and scoring for three-of-a-kind or better. \n\t      If a player only has two-of-a-kind, they may re-throw the remaining dice in an \n\t      attempt to improve the matching dice values. If no matching numbers are\n\t      rolled, a player scores 0. The first player to reach 25 points wins. ");
        Console.WriteLine("\nScoring: 3-Of-A-Kind = 3 Points \n         4-Of-A-Kind = 6 Points \n         5-Of-A-Kind = 12 Points\n");

        Random RandomNum = new Random();
        Player[] player1 = new Player[5];
        Die[] myDie = new Die[5];


        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            myDie[i] = new Dice_v4.Die(RandomNum);
            player1[i] = new Dice_v4.Player();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)   // Number of players
        {
            Console.Write("Enter Name for Player {0}:", i + 1);
            string NewName = Console.ReadLine();
            player1[i].SetName(NewName);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress enter in turns to roll the five dice");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();


        for (int j = 1; j < 50; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {

                myDie[i].roll();
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Rolled:{1} on the first dice", player1[i].GetName(), myDie[i].GetTopNumber());
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Rolled:{1} on the second dice", player1[i].GetName(), myDie[i].GetTopNumber1());
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Rolled:{1} on the third dice", player1[i].GetName(), myDie[i].GetTopNumber2());
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Rolled:{1} on the fourth dice", player1[i].GetName(), myDie[i].GetTopNumber3());
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Rolled:{1} on the fifth dice", player1[i].GetName(), myDie[i].GetTopNumber4());
                myDie[i].points();                    
                Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t\t\tTotal Throws:{0}\n ------------------------------------------------------", j);
                myDie[i].Totally();
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
        }

    }

   }
```

Points :

```
class Die
{


    private int NumberTop1;                  //attributes
    private int NumberTop2;
    private int NumberTop3;
    private int NumberTop4;
    private int NumberTop5;

    int threepoints = 0;
    int sixpoints = 0;
    int twelvepoints = 0;
    int TotalPoints = 0;

    private Random RandomNumGenerator;

    public Die(Random RandomGenerator)       // constructor
    {
        RandomNumGenerator = RandomGenerator;        // initialises random number
    }

    public int GetTopNumber()
    {
        return NumberTop1;          // Returns number on top 
    }

    public int GetTopNumber1()
    {
        return NumberTop2;
    }

    public int GetTopNumber2()
    {
        return NumberTop3;
    }

    public int GetTopNumber3()
    {
        return NumberTop4;
    }

    public int GetTopNumber4()
    {
        return NumberTop5;
    }

    public void roll()
    {
        NumberTop1 = RandomNumGenerator.Next(1, 7);
        NumberTop2 = RandomNumGenerator.Next(1, 7);
        NumberTop3 = RandomNumGenerator.Next(1, 7);
        NumberTop4 = RandomNumGenerator.Next(1, 7);
        NumberTop5 = RandomNumGenerator.Next(1, 7);

        List<int> diceValues = new List<int>();
        diceValues.Add(GetTopNumber());
        diceValues.Add(GetTopNumber1());
        diceValues.Add(GetTopNumber2());
        diceValues.Add(GetTopNumber3());
        diceValues.Add(GetTopNumber4());


        var duplicates = diceValues
        .GroupBy(i => i)
        .Where(g => g.Count() == 3)
        .Select(g => g.Key);
        foreach (var d in duplicates)
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("\n{0} Appeared three times --- 3 Points Awarded\n", d);
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black; threepoints += 3;
        }

        var fourting = diceValues
         .GroupBy(i => i)
       .Where(g => g.Count() == 4)
       .Select(g => g.Key);
        foreach (var e in fourting)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n{0} Appeared four times --- 6 Points Awarded\n", e);
            sixpoints += 6;
        }

        var fiveting = diceValues
      .GroupBy(i => i)
      .Where(g => g.Count() == 5)
      .Select(g => g.Key);
        foreach (var f in fiveting)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n{0} Appeared five times  --- 12 Points Awarded\n", f);
            twelvepoints += 12;
        }
    }
 public string points()
    {
        TotalPoints = threepoints + sixpoints + twelvepoints;
        Console.WriteLine("\n\t\t\t\t\tTotal Score: {0}", TotalPoints);

        return pointss;
    }



    public string Totally()
    {
        if (TotalPoints >= 25)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This Player Won the game");

        } 
        return tots;
    }
 }
```

Comment: What is the value you are setting to variable `tots` before returning from `Totally` in Dice class? How are you summing up the values in `TotalPoints` in Dice class?

Comment: nothing as I understand. I was just playing around trying to get it working

Comment: If you are not clear about the logic then it is very difficult to answer the question. Even if we answer the question and if you can't get the logic of it there is not point. Can you share the Entire Dice Class ?

Comment: Your Die class does not make sense, and you aren't showing the classes being used in the program (`Dice_v4.Die`, for example). A die should not know anything about a player, or "Total points". If you think about the object, it has two main features: The ability to `Roll()`, and the `FaceValue` property. I would suggest revisiting your object design and draw out a workflow diagram for the code before writing anything more.

Comment: Updated the Dice class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first need to change `Totally()` method of Dice class to a property as following.

```
public class Dice
{
    public int TotalScore
    {
        get { return TotalPoints; }
    }
}
```

I am not sure why you need to loop for 50 times.

You can use following logic.

```
private static void quickgame()    ---- Game carried out
{
    // All other code....

    bool anyPlayerWon = false;
    int totalThrows = 0;
    while(!anyPlayerWon)
    {
        totalThrows += 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            myDie[i].roll();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Rolled:{1} on the first dice", 
                player1[i].GetName(), myDie[i].GetTopNumber());
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Rolled:{1} on the second dice", 
                player1[i].GetName(), myDie[i].GetTopNumber1());
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Rolled:{1} on the third dice", 
                player1[i].GetName(), myDie[i].GetTopNumber2());
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Rolled:{1} on the fourth dice", 
                player1[i].GetName(), myDie[i].GetTopNumber3());
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Rolled:{1} on the fifth dice", 
                player1[i].GetName(), myDie[i].GetTopNumber4());
            myDie[i].points();                    
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t\t\tTotal Throws:{0}\n ----------------    --------------------------------------", totalThrows);
            var totalScore = myDie[i].TotalScore;
            if(totalScore >= 25)
            {
                anyPlayerWon = true;
                Console.WriteLine("This Player Won the game");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```